# SIGINT only received on child process if explicitly caught

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, sigint

I have the following test C program with UNIX system calls:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void abide(int sig_num) {
    printf("I, sleeper, will abide to this signal %d!\n", sig_num);
    fflush(stdout);
    exit(0);
}

void refuse(int sig_num) {
    signal(SIGINT, refuse);
    printf("I, sleeper, REFUSE this signal %d!\n", sig_num);
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "refuse") == 0) {
        signal(SIGINT, refuse);
    } else if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "deaf") == 0) {
        printf("I, sleeper, have been made deaf...\n");
    } else {
        signal(SIGINT, abide);
    }
    printf("I, sleeper, am now sleeping for 10s...\n");
    sleep(10);
    printf("I, sleeper, has terminated normally.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then I have another program which acts as a little shell. At my testing point, it forks and makes the child program execute the program above (with appropriate arguments). This shell is also ignoring Ctrl+C commands by use of

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
```

The results are the following:

```
MyShell> ./sleeper
I, sleeper, am now sleeping for 10s...
^CI, sleeper, will abide to this signal!
MyShell> ./sleeper refuse
I, sleeper, am now sleeping for 10s...
^CI, sleeper, REFUSE this signal!
I, sleeper, has terminated normally.
MyShell> ./sleeper deaf
I, sleeper, have been made deaf...
I, sleeper, am now sleeping for 10s...
^C^C^C^C    <---- not terminating
```

The first run seems correct. The second one is a bit strange as we are effectively ignoring the signal, but the program terminates anyway. Maybe it's because we're calling `sleep()` which is interrupted.

But it's the third result that confuses me. In a regular shell the program terminates, but in my custom shell nothing happens. It keeps running. Shouldn't the sleeper program's default signal handler (which terminates it also) execute just as abide() does?

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: The output from the first run is expected?  Your `abide` function calls `exit()`, yet you're still seeing the last `printf` output from `main`?

Comment: My bad. I copied the output over wrong. I edited the post.

Comment: You appear to have just edited that out, which leads me to think that what you're showing us isn't the *real* console output...

Comment: I was copying it over by eye, so that's why that mistake crept in. The rest is correct as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. The problem was a bit subtle. After using `fork()`, child processes apparently inherit their parents signal handlers, even if you use the `exec()` system calls afterwards. So the child process for `sleeper` was using the ignore handler. The solution was simply to add the default handler

`signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL)`

between the calls to `fork()` and `exec()`.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.  Children do not inherit signal handlers across an `exec`.  After `exec` the original text segement (i.e. the code including the handlers) is vaporized so what is there to inherit?  What would the address of the handler point to?  Instead what the OS does after `exec` is reset any signal with a handler to its default disposition.  So I guess I don't understand your problem or the solution.  Are you leaving something out?

Comment: Not as far as I know. It works as expected if I explicitly reset the signal handler to default before I call exec, and not if I don't. I'm running Linux 3.2.0-61-generic according to `uname`. I'm using `execvp` in particular.

Comment: I would suggest doubling checking.  I suspect you have a separate error somewhere.  Perhaps re-post a question with all the code, parent & child, in question.

Comment: Sure. Here is the shell code (for a school assignment). http://pastebin.com/y6v95Hta I've double checked that they correspond to the given outputs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where/how did you learn yourself about how the signal handler inheritance should behave?

Comment: I am not sure where I first learned it but it is in `man 7 signal`: A child created via fork(2) inherits a copy of its parent's signal dispositions.  During an execve(2), the dispositions  of  handled  signals  are reset to the default; the dispositions of ignored signals are left unchanged.

Comment: I compiled and ran your shell.  All 4 cases worked as expected including the "deaf" case.  It died on the signal as it should.  My guess is that in the heat of the moment you made some mistake - ran an old version or whatever - and started chasing a phantom.

Comment: Thanks! Might as well keep it like it is, then, whether it helps or not. I feel superstitious today.